# unable to use telerik mvc extension under area like admin

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am new to MVC & Telerik MVC control. I have added Telerik.Web.Mvc dll (2013.2.611.340) from nuget in my sample project. I have followed the following steps to configure Telerik control (asp.net MVC 4-5)
([From this URL](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/12-03-08/using-the-telerik-extensions-in-asp-net-mvc4-today---a-first-look.aspx))

1 Added  under namespaces tag in all in my web.config

2 Added

```
 <sectionGroup name="telerik">
  <section name="webAssets" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebAssetConfigurationSection, Telerik.Web.Mvc" requirePermission="false"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

in my web.config

I am able to use this extension control in my rood site, but unable to get reference in Area like admin area.

Anyone help to figure this out ?
I found that there was no issue with extension. The real issue is with Area. I am unable to get intellisense of any html helper (not even for third party like telerik)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik MVC Extensions was deprecated a while ago.

You want to look at [Telerik Kendo UI](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui).

[image]

Comment: Are this control free for use ? I want to use for learning and Admin panel.

Comment: [Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core?gclid=CjwKEAjw2f2hBRCdg76qqNXfkCsSJABYAycPFg_CsJjGTw-awljWfrJ1aZrBYma-wNH9hrHortpHUxoCC-_w_wcB) is open source and free. Grid, Chart, Editor, Scheduler and some are not free. [See the comparison](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison)

Comment: Still i have the base issue , Unable to get intellisence for view that are under admin area (I have created asp.net mvc area called 'admin' ) !!

Comment: [Kendo UI Visual Studio Intellisense](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/vs-intellisense)

Comment: Issue fixed , I have developed new MVC project and copy paste it config to my current project.

Comment: If this answer fixes your problem, please mark it as Answer. It'll help others who look for the same answer.